# Showing key error when calling a specific value from dataframe

Tags: python, keyerror

Code:

```
Dividend = key_stats_df.loc[r'Trailing annual dividend rate']
Dividend
```

[image: Input]
[image: Output]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also, you never asked a question.

Comment: `for x in df.index.tolist() : print(x, x == 'Trailing annual dividend rate')` and you'll see if you wrote it well

Comment: I tried to call the value of the "Trailing annual dividend rate" which is 0.87 but it results in calling all the headings like Trailing annual dividend rate and others and doesn't provide any value.